# Show that the evolute of a regular curve is regular if the curvature is nonzero

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, plane-curves

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $\alpha(s) = (x(s), y(s))$ be a **regular** curve parametrized by arc lenght. 
> Let $\beta(s) = \alpha(s) + \frac{1}{k(s)} \cdot n(s) $, where $k(s)$ is the **curvature** of $\alpha(s)$ and $n(s) = (-y(s), x(s))$ is the normal vector function. 
> (a) Prove that $\beta$ is differentiable if $k(s) \neq 0 \;\; \forall s$.  *[I've done that]* 
> (b) Prove that, if $k(s) \neq 0 \;\; \forall s$, then $\beta$ is regular if $k'(s) \neq 0 \;\; \forall s$. *[I'm stuck here]*.
>
> - A curve $\alpha(s)$ is **regular** if $\lvert \alpha(s) \rvert \neq 0 \;\; \forall s$.
> - The **curvature** of a curve $\alpha(s) = (x(s), y(s))$ parametized by arc length is $k(s) = \langle t'(s), n(s)\rangle$, where $t'(s) = (x''(s), y''(s))$.

What I have already done:

I have derived $\beta$ and found that
$$\beta'(s) = \alpha'(s) + \frac{k(s)}{k^2(s)} \cdot n'(s) - \frac{k'(s)}{k^2(s)} \cdot n(s).$$

I have tried proving the contrapositive, by supposing the existence of a number $s$ such that $\lvert \beta'(s) \rvert = 0$. This led me to $\beta'(s) = (0,0)$, and so

$$ \left(x' - \frac{k}{k^2}\cdot y'' + \frac{k'}{k^2}\cdot y' \;,\; y' + \frac{k}{k^2}\cdot x'' - \frac{k'}{k^2}\cdot x' \right) = (0,0). $$

Finally, I multiplied by $k^2$ to obtain two equalities:

$$ k^2 x' - k y'' + k'y' = 0 $$
$$ k^2 y' - k x'' + k'x' = 0. $$

Now I just can't seem to find a contradiction.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Try to simplify the first two terms of
$$
  \beta = \alpha'(s) + \frac{k(s)}{k^2(s)} n'(s) - \frac{k'(s)}{k^2(s)} n(s).
$$
The curve is parametrized by arc length so $\alpha'(s)$ is equal to what vector?
And use the Frenet-Serret formula to write $n'(s)$ in terms of the Frenet frame.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was it! I had thought about using the Frenet formulas, but couldn't see exactly how it would help. In case anyone is interested in the details, $\alpha'(s) = t(s)$ and $n'(s) = - k(s) t(s)$, so the first two terms cancel out, and $\beta'(s) = \frac{-k'(s)}{k^2(s)} n(s)$. It is then easy to see that $\beta'$ is always nonzero, since both $k'(s)$ and $n(s)$ are nonzero, which leads to $\lvert \beta'(s) \rvert$ being nonzero and thus $\beta$ is regular.

Comment: That is correct. Well done!